# nested for loop for symbols

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int h, l, x, y;
    printf("Enter the length of the box : ");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    printf("Enter the height of the box : ");
    scanf("%d", &h);

   for(x=1; x<=l; x++) {
       printf("z ");
   }
   for(y=2; y<=h; y++) {
       printf("\nz ");
   }
}
```

I know some codes are missing, I deleted them because they won't work.
Please tell me what to add to get it to work as below.

eg : input l = 5, h = 3

current output :

z z z z z

z

z

expected output :

z z z z z

z z z z z

z z z z z

Comment: Indent your code correctly, and you will see that you don't have nested/inner loop.

Comment: The term "nested loop" means that you put one loop inside the other so that the inner loop executes for each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You need nested loops for simplest -

```
  for(x=1; x<=h; x++)              // condition changed to x<=h
   {             
     for(y=1; y<=l; y++)           //condition changed to y<=l
      {          
           printf("z ");
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
```

**2.**  `void main()` **->** `int main(void)`

What you have right now are not `nested for loop's` .They are both independent loops.Thus you don't get correct output.

Answer (score 1):

quite a few things are missing ( not just some codes )

```
    for(y=0; y<h; y++){ 
            for(x=0; x<l; x++){
                    printf("z ");
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
```

and

> warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’